# How to give absolute URL in angualrjs TemplateUrl

Tags: .net, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
.state('home', {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'http://*********.net/*******/Views/Home.htm',
    controller: 'HomeController'
})
    .state('history', {
    name: 'history',
    url: '/history/:frid',
    templateUrl: 'http://*********.net/*******/Views/History.htm',
    controller: 'HistoryController'
})
```

I want to bind HTML files on the fly.....But I'm unable to do this with my angualarjs application.

Its append to current URL like:

```
localhost://8000:http://*********.net/*******/Views/History.htm
```

and it fails to load.

Please help on this issue.

Also I'm getting in console.. cross-browser exception to get HTML form remote resource

Comment: Why can't you use relative URL's and what does `bind HTML files on the fly` mean?

Comment: I want to be build hybrid mobile app .... that's why i want to put My js and views on fly(server) and want to be build with ionic framework for using native controls like camera,contact.... All is fine if my views and js are in same root ....but there is a problem is always app will be update by user....thats why i want to put my js and views on fly that i can change the view and js....no need to update app again for customer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a service in angular called `$sce` ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)) which is used to configure which contexts should be considered harmful and vice verca.
In documentation there is a paragraph about how it affects loading templates ([here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#impact-on-loading-templates)). In short, angular by default allows to load templates only from the same domain and protocol as your application unless you whitelist some another domain. You could do this with the help of `$sceDelegateProvider` ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider)).

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    // Allow same origin resource loads.
    'self',
    // Allow loading from your templates domain
    'http://some.example.com/**'
]);
```

Also you have to configure [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) on a server you are serving templates from.

Comment: I want to be build hybrid mobile app  .... that's  why i want to put My js and views on fly(server) and want to be build with ionic framework for using native controls like camera,contact.... All is fine if my views and js are in same root ....but there is a problem is always app will be update by user....thats why i want to put my js and views on fly that i can change the view and js....no need to update app again for customer.

Comment: config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) { $stateProvider .state('home', { name: 'home', url: '/home', templateUrl: 'http://*******.com/lalith/Home.htm', controller: 'HomeController' })

Comment: Ok...and what's the problem?

Comment: Problem when im gives the Abssolute path of my html page like templateUrl:'www.*******.net/lalith/Home.htm' it will gives exception of cross browser exception does allow remote resource,....how to achieve it. my html is simple like <ion-view title='home'><ion-content> my form forms </ion-content> </ion-view>

Comment: it give eroor like this....Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:49948/views/home.htm. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. home.htm

Comment: The error message says exactly how you can fix it: `This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. home.htm`. If moving to the same domain does not fit your demands, then do enable CORS for your domain which you use to serve templates.

Comment: For Ionic you can use [Cordova Whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) plugin to configure a list of trusted resources.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. Cross-Browser-Problem effect on Browsers but not in android device. Now im getting my Js and Views from server..... set  the cors for resource server...Thanks to Michael